# Why this python code still returns none?

Tags: python

I wrote this program to calculate the number of days you have lived, when you use the current date and your date of birth as the inputs (no matter which one first as long its in format: y,m,d. this is my first code ever, so it might be structured poorly, however I'm trying to see why it returns none?

```
def past_presenter(year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2):
  if year1>year2:
    year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2 = year2,month2,day2,year1,month1,day1
    return year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2
  else:
    if month1>month2:
      year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2 = year2,month2,day2,year1,month1,day1
      return year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2
    else:
      if day1>day2:
        year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2 = year2,month2,day2,year1,month1,day1
        return year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2

def absolute(y,m,d):
  if y<0:
    y=y*-1
  if m<0:
    m=m*-1
  if d<0:
    d=d*-1
  return y,m,d

def days(year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2):
  y=year2-year1
  m=month2-month1
  d=day2-day1
  y,m,d = absolute(y,m,d)
  days=d+(m*30)+(y*30*12)
  return days


def daysBetweenDates(year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2):
  year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2 = past_presenter(year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2)
  dd = days(year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2)
  return dd


print daysBetweenDates(2017,2,10,1980,1,1)
```

Comment: Aaaaand what about leap days? Don't roll your own date calculations. Just use `datetime`. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html

Comment: Not to mention that not every month has 30 days.....

Comment: @JackManey I wrote this code as practice. my problem is that I keep getting none as output. even when i call the function `days(1880,12,30,1990,1,1)` still doesnt work

Comment: @KOOLz When I run your exact code, and call `print(days(1880,12,30,1990,1,1))`, it outputs `39959`. I have no idea if that's correct or not, but I can't reproduce your issue. Are you not printing the value or anything? You can't just call the function and have it output the value. You have to explicitly print it.

Comment: Output is `None`... at which step?  I see there's a missing  else statement for `past_presenter` after `if day1>day2`

Comment: @RandomDavis maybe its my noobism at work, but I'm assuming that the proper output must be just and only '39959' however when i run the code at 'https://repl.it/languages/python'  i get: '39959 => None' . meaning i also get a none. so it is my noobism ar work?

Comment: @KOOLz On that site, if I put in `print('Hello, world!')` as the program, it outputs `Hello, world! => None`. That seems to be what that site is doing, it's not your code that's outputting that.

Comment: @KOOLz You should download Python and run the code on your computer rather than using that website. I'm not sure why it's saying None but it has nothing to do with your code. Even just the code 
print "hello" outputs ->None after printing "hello"

Comment: It is a funny coincidence though that the code also does have an error that will cause NoneType to be returned... just not with the test case he used.

Answer (score 0):

When I copy paste your code and run it I get 13359 returned by your test case. However, I do see your mistake. Test cases where year1 < year2 will return None because past_presenter returns None, you are missing a return statement at the end of all your if statements. All the return statements are nested within "if year1 > year2" so it returns nothing when year2>=year1.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved, because the code is fine, but the platform it was being tested on: 'https://repl.it/languages/python' always outputs none no matter what the code